# Mongoose : filter on an subdocument attribute

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, find, subdocument

I have a subdocument Schema (federation) in my stage Schema :

```
// Stage Schema
const stageSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    ...
    federation: federationSchema,
    ...

// Subdocument Schema
const federationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  nom: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  groupeId: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Groupe',
    required: false,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
});
```

I want to select all the stages that have a name of federation equal to "toto"
So I tried :

```
const filter = {}
filter.federation = { nom: 'toto'}
..
await Stage.find(filter).
```

But 0 stages are returned...
Is my filter correct ?

Comment: I think you need [dot notation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks !

```
filter['federation.nom'] = 'toto';
```